# Elm returning integer instead of Bool, compiler bug?

Tags: boolean, elm, compiler-bug

Function signature clearly states that it should return a Bool so why is the function returning 96? What is more, compiler thinks that 96 is actually a Bool. Is this a bug?

```
> isLeapYear year =\
|       (modBy 4 year == 0) && (modBy 100 year /= 0) || (modBy 400 year == 0)
<function> : Int -> Bool

> isLeapYear 1996
96 : Bool
```

It seems to work sometimes though:

```
> isLeapYear 2000
True : Bool
> isLeapYear 1800
False : Bool
```

Comment: Yea, it definitely looks like a bug and I'm able to reproduce it using the `/=` operator against a `0` on either side. For example, `1 /= 0` and `0 /= 1` both yield `1 : Bool` while `1 /= 2` yields the expected `True : Bool`

Comment: Probably a repl bug rather than a compiler bug though. I doubt an issue like this in actual compiled code would have gone unnoticed for so long.

Comment: It's an issue in a compiled code, just checked by printing it into a webapp. It is also in the  `elm-test` output.

Comment: [Here is an Ellie example that shows this is a bug in compiled code](https://ellie-app.com/4DVRQBqYq5Ja1). It prints two list of booleans, the first modding by 0 and showing an integer instead of a bool, and the second list modding by 1 and showing a boolean appropriately. I would wager the problem involves `Debug.print` since it is not just in the REPL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a [compiler bug](https://github.com/elm/compiler/issues/1810) which I filed last year and which has now been fixed.

It affects only the `/=` operator when one argument is `0`: replacing `(modBy 100 year /= 0)` with `(not (modBy 100 year == 0))` will work around the problem.

The bug has been fixed in the source repository, but I don't know when the fix will be released.